# Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" (type string) at path "_id" for model "ToDo"

Tags: reactjs, node.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ncE0.png)
`const handleUpdateStatus = async (id, status) => { console.log(id);  try {   const response = await ToDoServices.updateToDo(id, {   isCompleted: status,   });   console.log(response.data);   message.success("Task updated successfully");   getAllToDo();  } catch (error) {   console.log(error);   message.error(getErrorMessage(error));   } };`
`const updateToDo = ({ id, data }) => {   return axios.patch(SERVER_URL + "/update-to-do/" + id, data, authHeaders()); };`
`<Tooltip title="Mark as completed"> <CheckCircleFille onClick={() => handleUpdateStatus(item._id, false)}/>`

I checked the item object :
Editing item
Object { _id: "65f1b56d1c3e0e7766cbd8ae", title: "todo1", description: "todo1", isCompleted: true, createdBy: "65f08e42a72f7f2125ef5df6", createdAt: "2024-03-13T14:17:17.244Z", updatedAt: "2024-03-13T14:17:17.244Z", __v: 0 }
}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.